# Using the moderator flag when other flags don't apply

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, declined-flags, moderation

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611349/recurrence-big-theta) now removed question, and I felt that it should be closed because it doesn't seem to fit the standard for questions on SO. However, I didn't feel like it fit into the close reasons (most likely I would have used the "Too Localized" flag if it still existed, but it doesn't), so instead I flagged it for moderator attention with the following note:

> This is a specific homework question that doesn't show any actual
>   effort, and it isn't phrased in a way that will be useful to people
>   other than the OP. I don't think it falls into any of the typical
>   close reasons (it is on topic, not too broad, not technically a
>   duplicate, etc), but I think it should be closed, so I wanted to
>   notify a moderator

The moderator flag was then declined with the message, "Please choose a standard close vote reason".

Was it incorrect for me to use the moderator flag here? If so, what standard close reason should I have used?

Note: I don't have 10k rep, so I can't post a copy of the original question, but if someone with high rep wants to post it or part of it for reference, I would appreciate that. It would help people to see the question and therefore know what kind of close reason would best apply

Comment: You shouldn't flag questions for moderators to close. Moderators should only be involved in things that cannot be handled by the community - closing questions isn't one of those things.  If you can't find a close reason for a question, then maybe it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @bluefeet That's good to know, thanks. My misunderstanding was that because there wasn't a close reason that fit, that made it fall under "A problem not listed above", but that seems to not be the case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **unclear what you're asking**
>   Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

The question you flagged was severely lacking in detail. Heck, it didn't even contain the problem it asked for a solution to, merely a link to an image of it. The problem statement was literally "I do not know what to do next."

If you were going to close it, this would've been the appropriate reason.

As it came out, simply downvoting was sufficient to convince the asker to get rid of his own question. This is a pretty good example of how [allowing askers to delete their own terrible questions can save everyone a lot of work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276027/should-heavily-edited-answers-block-self-deletion-of-questions).

Comment: Fair enough, I felt at the time it wasn't unclear because it seemed like someone could answer it with the details given (since it was essentially a homework problem), but you are right that they didn't ask a specific enough question. Thanks for the clarification, and I'll keep that in mind next time I come across that kind of question